# Is Mac developers privacy guaranteed?

Tags: macos, security, privacy

There are a lot of threads about user privacy in the MacOS ecosystem. But what about the developer privacy?

If I sign a Mac app using my Apple developer account for distribution outside of the App Store (Developer ID Application), is it possible for users to get information such as my email or developer name?
My Apple developer account was created using my personal email address and full name, and for obvious reasons I don't want that sensible information to be inside the apps I sign.

How much information about a developer is possible to get from a signed app?

Thanks.